# How do I convert a CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream to ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, networking, encryption, network-programming

I am writing an encrypted Server/Client system and I need to be able to encrypt objects (Packets) over the network. My problem involves creating the ObjectOutput and Input streams from the CipherInput and Output Streams.

Firstly, (on the client end), when I create my ObjectInputStream, it just hangs there:

```
    public void connectToServer(String serverIP, int port)
    {
    try 
    {
        socket = new Socket(serverIP, port);                                
        key = KeyGeneratorWrapper.getEncryptionKey();                       // KeyGen
        encryptedSocket = new SecretSocket(socket, key);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(encryptedSocket.getOutputStream());    
        in = new ObjectInputStream(encryptedSocket.getInputStream());   // HANGS HERE   
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Secondly, (If i comment out making the inputstream on the client side), when I actually send an object from the client to the server, the server keeps waiting for an object to be sent through:

```
            Socket socket = null;   // Client's Socket
            socket = serverSocket.accept();                                          // Wait for a new connection
            key = KeyGeneratorWrapper.getEncryptionKey();                            // Get key for encryption/decryption
            encryptedSocket = new SecretSocket(socket, key);                        // Create secure communication path to receive/send data on
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(encryptedSocket.getOutputStream());        // Get the output stream
            in = new ObjectInputStream(encryptedSocket.getInputStream());           // Get the input stream for client socket

            Packet clientDetails = null;

            clientDetails = (Packet)(in.readObject());// SERVER WAITS HERE
            System.out.println("Received");
```

Please note that the "encryptedSocket" returns the CipherOutput and Input Streams

Here is the code for "SecretSocket":

```
public class SecretSocket
{
private Key key;                        // Encryption key
private Cipher inCipher;                // Decryption Cipher
private Cipher outCipher;               // Encryption Cipher
private CipherInputStream in;           // Cipher incoming data
private CipherOutputStream out;         // Cipher outgoing data

private Socket socket;                  // UNSAFE COMMUNICATION SOCKET

public static String ALGORITHM = "DES"; // Encryption algorithm
private String currentAlgorithm;        // Current encryption algorithm being used

public SecretSocket(Socket s, Key key)
{
    this.key = key;
    socket = s;
    currentAlgorithm = ALGORITHM;
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Create encryption and decryption ciphers
 * @param input
 */
public void initialize()
{
       try 
       {
            outCipher = Cipher.getInstance(currentAlgorithm);
            outCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            inCipher = Cipher.getInstance(currentAlgorithm);
            inCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

/**
 * Return incomming datastream
 * @param input
 */
public InputStream getInputStream()
{
    InputStream is = null;
    try 
    {
        is = socket.getInputStream();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    in = new CipherInputStream(is, inCipher);
    return in;
}

/**
 * Return outgoing datastream
 * @param input
 */
public OutputStream getOutputStream()
{
    OutputStream os = null;
    try 
    {
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out = new CipherOutputStream(os, outCipher);
    return out;
}
```

}

Comment: `SecretSocket`? What's that?

Comment: The secretSocket takes in a socket and creates the Cipher streams for it

Comment: I guess that's relevant information for the question then. Please include the code for it in the question.

Comment: Does the code work without the cryptography?

Comment: Yes, with normal sockets and objectOutputStreams it works perfectly (obviously this is not all the code though)

Comment: Could you try buffering your `CipherInputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream` of at least 8 bytes?

Comment: How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream, inCipher);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(cis);
```

Comment: GhostCat
A) Im not an expert sorry, just sharing what worked for me
B) yeah u are im sorry i had forgotten the instance of the cipher, i have edited can u try to compile it again..

Comment: Thanx for the correction, it had slipped my fingers

Answer (score -1):

You need to  flush the `ObjectOutputStream` after creating it. Otherwise the peer will block at `new ObjectInputStream(...)`. This isn't always so, but it is so when there is an underlying buffered stream or cipher stream.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that my client does in fact send a Packet over on connect (in a different method)